# spacemacs - python layer repl loads with horizontal split

Tags: python, vertical-alignment, spacemacs

In spacemacs, I must have pressed a strange combination, because when I press `C-c C-p` my `ipython` repl loads with a side by side split - how can I switch this back to a stacked split permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html):

> If `split-height-threshold` is smaller than the chosen window’s height, the split puts the new window below. Otherwise, if `split-width-threshold` is smaller than the window’s width, the split puts the new window on the right.

Therefore add the following to `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
(setq split-height-threshold 0)
```